# add color info into checkbox folder dat.gui

Tags: javascript, dat.gui

Is it possible to add color information into checkbox folder? Like on the picture.

I know there exists color controller, but I just need checkbox with information about color, which it represents (TCP is red, UDP is purple,...).
I tried to google it, but unsuccessfully.

[image: dat gui folders]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify the DOM elements for each gui option however you want.

```
var checkbox = gui.add( obj, ‘showTCP’ )
checkbox.domElement.classList.add(‘blue’)
```